# Validate restriction in Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have the following ClaimType in a custom policy to test out collecting user timezone during sign up:

```
  <ClaimType Id="extension_timezone">
    <DisplayName>Timezone</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Enter your timezone</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Enumeration Text="(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)" Value="(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)" SelectByDefault="false" />
      <Enumeration Text="(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" Value="(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" SelectByDefault="false" />
      <Enumeration Text="(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" Value="(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London" SelectByDefault="true" />
      <Enumeration Text="(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington" Value="(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington" SelectByDefault="false" />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

This displays correctly in the sign up flow but I have noticed that the input is not validated against the restriction. Steps:

1. Select item from drop-down
2. Use browser tools (e.g. Chrome DevTools) to change the value of the selected option
3. Submit the form

I would expect there to be validation to check that the submitted value matches one of the enumeration entries, but this does not happen. I can include extension_timezone in the output claims and see that the value reflects the changes I made that do not match any of the enumeration options.

Comment: Regarding the browser tools change the value and missing validation will investigate further

Comment: @GovindSharma-MSFTIdentity the answer does not resolve my question. I require validation to occur without using custom jQuery. I would prefer for this validation to occur on the server side but the client side would be better than nothing.

Comment: @AlasdairStark did you ever find a solution to this? We have just discovered the same issue

Comment: Nope. It's not ideal :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own validation rules using jQuery which is loaded by both v1 and v2 policies.

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) for gudelines and samples of using Javascript

Comment: I want to avoid going down the route of using JavaScript in my policies. I expect there to be server-side validation of restrictions defined in policies.